# Full Bridge Rectifier Schematic Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac-dc, full-bridge, schematic

I am working on a circuit of an old 90's Terminal Applicator and noticed it has AC power coming in, then stepped down with a transformer, and then going to a pair of full bridge rectifiers. One goes to a 12V linear regulator, and the other goes to a 5V linear regulator.

The 12V regulator circuit makes sense. AC lines from the transformer go to the rectifier and GND and AC is set. However, the 5V regulator circuit doesn't make sense. It only one AC line and where the other AC line should be, it is going to ground.

The C9 capacitor going into the 12V regulator is a 470uF, 25V electrolytic cap. The C2 capacitor going into the 5V regulator is a 1000uF, 10V electrolytic cap.

How does that work?

Below is the schematic I traced of the PCB:

[image: AC to DC conversion]

Here is the PCB fully populated out of the Molex terminal applicator.
[image: Populated PCB by Molex]

Here is the rectifiers and note where the TO-220 7805 and 7812 are as well as the C2 and C9 capacitors:

[image: Rectifiers]

Here is the backside of the PCB. I drew the top-side components on the back. Notice how the Rectifier REC1 has an AC line tied to what is known to be ground?
[image]

Latest edit. I finally got the rectifiers off the PCB. It is a fact. Molex did tie one of the transformer's stepped down AC lines to ground on REC1, I highlighted it as proof. I know the machine operated, so I know it works. I just don't know how.
[image]

Comment: I think you'll find that live and neutral don't go to those rectifiers (at least not in your schematic).

Comment: How about some pictures?

Comment: The main issue is that there are errors in the schematic.  You have node names mixed and shorted together, with wiring errors around the rectifiers.  You may want to just start over from the start.

Comment: But this is the traced PCB. The only part I couldnt trace was what was underneath the rectifiers as it was being troublesome. Where are the node names mixed and shorted together if that is how it is on the PCB on a known function Molex terminal applicator that's been running since the 90s?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does not work. Perhaps the reverse engineering has a mistake.

Looking at REC1 only, during the cycle where AC2 is positive and AC1 is negative, it would act as a half wave rectifier.

But when AC1 is positive and AC2 negative, they will be shorted through one diode in the bridge rectifier, between terminals marked "-" and "AC2".

Comment: That's what I am thinking. I desoldered everything except the full bridge rectifiers, as they are being very stubborn.

Answer (score 0):

Your post implies that AC1, AC2, and AC3 go to the mains Line (not Live) and Neutral.  If they do, they can *not* drive a 78xx regulator directly.  If you are in the US, the voltage across C2 and C9 would be over 150 V.

AC1, AC2 and AC3 almost certainly come from a power transformer.

That change does not relieve the problems with the bridge wiring.

And note the voltage ratings of the two main filter capacitors.  Can you update your question with the voltages on C2 and C9?

Comment: I am not in front of it at the moment, but yes, there is a step down transformer. I am not sure what it steps down to, but the capacitor voltage ratings I listed are the ones off the PCB